# apache-airflow installation in linux without root access - airflow command not found

Tags: airflow

I don't have root access to the linux m/c . 
Installed Airflow with a path prefix like ----
pip3 install --target='/dir/subdir' apache-airflow[postgres,ssh,jdbc]

Now, I am not able to find the executable "airflow" .

I tried as -

```
./dir/subdir/airflow/bin/airflow  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dir/subdir/airflow/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/dir/subdir/airflow/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from builtins import object
ImportError: No module named builtins
```

What am I missing here ? Any help is really appreciated .

Thanks,
KD